# Выбор папки в java

Tags: java, javafx

У меня простой вопрос:
Как реализовать выбор папки в java?

Comment: Использовать класс FileChooser?

Comment: он позволяет выбирать только фалы. вроде?

Comment: Тогда DirectoryChooser